# Two supposedly equivalent ways to typeset a space result in different renderings

Tags: fonts, tex-core, white-space

Consider the following TeX manuscript:

```
\font\myfont=cmtt14\myfont
x x

x\char32x
\end
```

When it is compiled with pdftex, it typesets thus:

[image: cmtt space]

Why is there a difference between the two rows in the way the space is rendered?

Comment: I have a feeling this might be an 'X-Y' question: is the aim purely interest or is there some application you have in mind?

Comment: @JosephWright: What's an 'X-Y' question? At any rate, it is partly out of pure interest, and partly because I'm experimenting with the way LaTeX3 deals with spaces inside token lists, and I'd like to be able to view the spaces readily.

Comment: An X-Y question is where someone asks one thing (X) but really wants to do another (Y). Here, to see tokens, typesetting them is not the right approach: one can decompose a token list easily in  `expl3` using `\tl_show_analysis:N`. I'll post a (non)-answer about the underlying problem shortly.

Comment: @JosephWright: OK, thanks. By the way, I don't understand how `\pdfinterwordspaceon` is meant to be used. I tried the example on p. 29 of [The pdfTeX User Manual](http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/systems/doc/pdftex/manual/pdftex-a.pdf) (April 20, 2017), but I see no difference between the spaces before the `\pdfinterwordspaceon` is used and afterwords. In particular, the spaces are not rendered as ␣'s.

Comment: `\char<number>` doesn't produce a token; it is an unexpandable construction that's sent directly to the typesetter, meaning “print character in slot `<number>` in the current font.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TeX does not use characters for spaces in output: rather these are 'gaps' between the glyphs. When you consider that characters are of fixed size whilst TeX is all about varying spacing to get 'good' paragraphs, that makes sense. As such, the glyph held at position 32 of a font has nothing to do with typesetting normal spaces: it doesn't even have to be space-related.

Recent efforts related to accessible and reflowable PDFs have led to the inclusion of 'faked' space inclusion primitives in pdfTeX: see `\pdfinterwordspaceon`. However, this relies on a specific font (which just contains a fake space), and is really not intended for general alteration of output. (To date this functionality is also not widely used and so may well nto work perfectly.)

Comment: Thanks. What about the (non)-answer you were going to post about the underlying problem? (Something involving `\tl_show_analysis:N`.)

Answer (score 8):

The construction `\char<number>` is conceptually different from typing the character with that number.

For instance, `` \char`\^^M `` will *not* produce an end-of-line character (with category code 5, under the normal TeX conventions). Similarly, `\char32` will *not* produce a space token.

The instruction `\char<number>` is passed directly to the typesetting stage, and means

> print the glyph in slot `<number>` of the current font

For instance, OT1 encoded fonts normally have the small slash for the Polish “suppressed ell”, that is ł and Ł. If you look in `plain.tex`, you'll find

```
663 \def\l{\char32l}
664 \def\L{\leavevmode\setbox0\hbox{L}\hbox to\wd0{\hss\char32L}}
```

(line numbers added for reference). However, fixed width font in the OT1 encoding have the “visible space” glyph in slot 32. Try processing with plain TeX

```
\l \quad \tt \l \bye
```

and you'll see.

It should be noted that characters inserted via `\char` will participate to hyphenation as if they were input directly (and fit some of the hyphenation patterns) and form ligatures, because ligatures are tied to the slots in the current font, rather than to character tokens.

```
\char`f lagsta\char`f \char`f

\leavevmode
\vbox{\hsize=0pt \hfuzz=\maxdimen % no warning
  \hskip 0pt supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
}\hskip 4em
\vbox{\hsize=0pt \hfuzz=\maxdimen % no warning
  \hskip 0pt superc\char`a lifr\char`a gilisticexpi\char`a lidocious
}

\l \tt \l

\bye
```

[image]